# Make the <hr> tag end the question excerpt

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

### Can we allow users to denote the end of the excerpt by use of a `<hr>` in the body of the question?

The purpose of the feature request is to make spoilers easier to hide in excerpts. Consider the following:

[image: New Question With Spoilers]

You can see I had to add padding to fill out the excerpt to hide the spoiler. If I could do something like the following instead:

```
<sub>I have seen every New Who episode, even if it has been some time, so spoilers 
are fine in answers.</sub>

---
```

[image]

And have that `---` (which becomes the `<hr>` in question) mark the end of the excerpt, it would result in something that looked like this:

[image]

This would enable us to ask questions freely and only worry about spoilers in titles (which is already a pain point for some), instead of having to also add ~200 characters of fluff to the question itself.

<sub>(and this doesn't even take into account the onebox in chat that has something like a 300 character excerpt. it could use the love as well)</sub>

Comment: I don't like the idea of artificially placing extra markup just to avoid an undesirable feature of the site.

Comment: I agree with @Möoz if you fear spoilers, don’t use the site, easy. Even easier, stop whining about spoilers.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use

> spoiler markup.

Just add `>!` at the beginning of a paragraph to hide the spoilers. This solves both the /questions page...

[image]

And chat oneboxes.

[image]

Comment: It's worth nothing that the spoiler markup does not handle adjacent blocks well, generally requiring manual line-breaks to make it all one block, or non-"quoted" text in between to break them up.